# Delete all files in a directory but not the directory every 24 hours

Tags: java, delete-file

I am looking to do some java, that will delete all the contents of a directory every 24 hours, what is the best approach to doing this? I have found a lot of ways using php but not java.

Answer (score 1):

> what is the best aproach to doing this

Assuming that you really need to do this in Java:

1. Write a java method that iterates over the files in a directory using (for example) `File.listFiles()`.  For each one call `File.delete()`.  (If the directory contains subdirectories, it will be a bit more complicated ... depending on what you want to happen for the subdirectories.
2. Write some java code that calls the previous method once every 24 hours.

References:

- The javadocs for [`java.io.File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html)
- The javadoc for [`java.util.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) which can be used to run a task periodically.

Alternatively, you might be able to find some existing code using Google.  (But I'm not going to look for you.)

Comment: Note, with Java SE 7 it's recommended to use the new NIO.2 File API.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said java ... but.. If you are using unix use crontab

```
crontab -e

0 1 * * * rm -rf /path/to/mydir/*
```

Delete all files in your dir at 1am every night

Answer (score 0):

And in a windows machine you can:

`at 00:00 /every:M,T,W,Th,F,S,Su "cmd /c del /f/s/q c:\path\to\dir"`

Which deletes everything (including subdirectories) in `c:\path\to\dir` quietly at `00:00` (midnight) everyday.

Use `at /delete` to disable the scheduled tasks.

You can read more about the At Utility [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726974.aspx).